# Why am I getting this error when selecting files with uigetfile?

Tags: matlab, file, selection, cell-array

I used `uigetfile` to select multiple images. When I select the images and push the open button or press the enter key everything is okay. But when I instead select the images and double click on the selected images, I get this error:

```
Cell contents reference from a non-cell array object.

Error in Picketfence>insertpb_Callback (line 141)
                file             = fullfile(PathName,FileNames{i});
```

Here's my code:

```
c={'*.*', 'All Files(*.*)';'*.jpeg','figure (*.jpg)';'*.tif',...
        'figure (*.tif)'};
    [FileNames,PathName] = uigetfile(c, 'Select Images','MultiSelect','on');

if char(FileNames)
    nfiles = length(FileNames);
    handles.profile = zeros(1024,1024);
    for i = 1:nfiles            
        file = fullfile(PathName,FileNames{i});                                
        handles.profile = handles.profile+im2double(imread(file));
    end
end
```

Why am I getting this error and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you can't select multiple files by double-click. When you select your files, then double-click on one of them, what's actually happening is that you are selecting **only** the one you double-clicked on. In other words, the first click of the double-click selects just that one, clearing the others.

When the GUI closes and returns to your code, you only have a single file selected, so `FileNames` isn't a cell array, just a character string. This is why the [cell content indexing](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/access-data-in-a-cell-array.html#zmw57dd0e30216) with `{}` fails.

**A few more points about your code...**

- Your conditional check `if char(FileNames)` is wrong. The [`char`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/char.html) function doesn't return logical (i.e. boolean) values. It converts things to character arrays. As per the documentation for [`uigetfile`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/uigetfile.html), the outputs will be zero when the selection is cancelled or the GUI closed, so the appropriate check in your case would be:

  ```
  if ~isequal(FileNames, 0)
    % Do your processing here...
  else
    % Nothing was selected; take some other action
  end
  ```
- You may want to account for the possibility of only 1 file being selected, thus having `FileNames` be a character array. The simplest way to do this is to first check if `FileNames` is a [character array](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/creating-character-arrays.html) using [`ischar`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ischar.html), and if so encapsulate it in a 1 element [cell array](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/cell-arrays.html) (since your code expects cell arrays):

  ```
  if ischar(FileNames)
    FileNames = {FileNames};
  end
  ```

  Then you can do all your processing as you have it written above.